# Converting .htaccess to lighttpd for a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I'm a newbie and am trying to convert a htaccess to lighttpd format but everything I try doesn't work.
I have a few rules for example.com and now I want to add a new subdirectory named /test and use htaccess rules just for that directory (is that even possible?).
Anyway, here's the htaccess I want to convert:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|css|js|swf|wav|avi|mpg|ttf|woff)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/ - [R=403,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [R=403,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.sa$ index.php?sa=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [PT,L]
```

Now, my guesswork solution was this, but it doesn't work and I don't understand how can I make it work:

```
   $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/test" {
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/(dashboard|admin)/" {
    url.access-deny = ("")
}
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?uri=$1",
    "^/(.*/).sa$" => "index.php?sa=$1",
)
server.follow-symlink = "enable"}
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lighttpd rewrite rules match against the full url-path + query-string, whereas `$HTTP["url"]` is just the url-path (yes, I can see how that can be a bit confusing) and `$HTTP["query-string"]` is just the query-string.

The following uses some syntax available in lighttpd 1.4.50 (released over a year ago)  The current version of lighttpd is lighttpd 1.4.54.  (If you're using, say, lightttpd 1.4.45, your distro is, uhhh, more than a tad behind)

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/(dashboard|admin)/" {
    url.access-deny = ("")
}
$HTTP["url"] !~ "\.(?i:gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|css|js|swf|wav|avi|mpg|ttf|woff)$" {
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
        "^(/.*)\.sa(\?.*)?$" => "index.php?sa=$1${qsa}",
        "" => "/index.php?uri=${url.path}${qsa}",
    )
}
server.follow-symlink = "enable"
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't work and now the whole rule applies to example.com in whole, not just for example.com/test.Also the rewrite isnt rewriting the urls (meaning that example.com/test/install won't give out example.com/test/index.php?uri=install or example.com/test/data.sa won't give out example.com/test/index.php?sa=data

Comment: The regexes you gave in your original post will never both match since they are both anchored to the beginning of the string: `   $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/test" {
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/(dashboard|admin)/" ...`.  I therefore assumed you made an obvious mistake.  If you want to add back the outer condition, go right ahead, and be sure to adjust the inner regexes.  Regarding the second part of your comment, I think that you are confused.  There is a difference between internal rewrites (mod_rewrite) and external redirects (mod_redirect).